# How to compare differences between two logistic regression models?

Tags: statistical-significance, nonlinear-regression

I've made non-linear estimation predicting percent of viable cells depending on drug dose given. The curves were fitted using the `y=a*ln(x)+b` equation, where `y` stands for the percent of viable cells, and `x` stands for concentration of drug.

The curves are quite well fitted and could be published, yet I would like to find out, if the curves are "statistically different" - is it possible to determine the significance of differences between them? Is it even a valid question?

Comparison between two most different models is presented below. The equations are:

```
y=(-18,7047)*log(x)+(128,96)

y=(-27,4459)*log(x)+(141,982)
```

[image]

Comment: I see a few places where you might be confused.1) Your graph indicates that 110% of cells are viable when the concentration is 10 ug/mL. 2) You don’t use the logistic regression link function, so you’re not doing logistic regression. // You might have a totally reasonable goal, and I think I know what you want to do (compare the orange (a,b) to the blue (a,b)) but it will help us if you can describe what you want to do, why you’re making a claim about 110% of cells being viable, how you’re using logistic regression, and what kind of “significance” interests you.

Comment: Thank you for your response! 
1) that's right. The function based on `y=a/(1+(b)*EXP(c*x))` would be more accurate (and do not exceed 100% of cell viability), yet in concentration range, in which we're interested (5-100 ug/ml), the equation mentioned in my question it is quite useful predictor - and is simpler. This "110% cell viability" is a disadvantage which I am aware of. I've also thought, it would be easier to compare, so I used it instead of equation with more parameters.

Comment: 2) It seems, that I've made a translation error; should I rather say about: "non-linear estimation based on  logarithm function"? And yes, all I need to determine is if I can say that Drug 2 have better/different effect than Drug 1. If it will be done by comparing the 'a' and 'b' parameters or any other means - it would be good. As long as I could confirm the difference - or its absence.

Answer (score 1):

In most types of regression, typical approach to compare the effect of a program (drug type) on certain outcome is to make one model for all the observations, and a dummy (0-1) variable for treatment:

$cells_i = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}drug\_type_i + \varepsilon_i$

If needed, other control variables may be included, such as:

$cells_i = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}drug\_type_i + \beta_{2}dose_i + \varepsilon_i$

If you feel, that structural parameter $\beta_2$ differs between groups, and for some reason you want to investigate it, you can perform [Chow test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_test) in order to test stability of parameters between two regressions, one for every group.

However, it should probably end up in a single model with an interaction:

$cells_i = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}drug\_type_i + \beta_{2}dose_i + \beta_{3}drug\_type_i \times dose_i+ \varepsilon_i$

---

Every variable in regression can be logarithmized, as @Dave correctly mentioned, it does not make it "logistic regression". It changes interpretation of variables for semielasticity, but do not change estimation method.